# CSS3 / late CSS2 cross browser compatibility (possibly with jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser

A certain project is producing marvellous results with use of the following CSS features:

`box-shaddow; border-radius; RGBA` colours on borders and backgrounds.

Problem is that the first two require late `Firefox / Chrome / Safari`

browsers and the second is incompatible on IE8 and below along with previous incarnations of `Firefox` and `Safari`.

So some of these features can be simulated with `PNG` images but it is a very extensive way of getting around the problem.

Is there a `jQuery` `plugin / function / procedure` that could mimic these 3 properties with reasonable similarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) might be what you are looking for. However, [HTML5 Please](http://html5please.com/) recommends not using a polyfill for these features, but only a reasonable fallback.

Answer (score 0):

AS stated on HTML Please:

> box-shadow is safe to use most of the time, except when you are applying it on a large area as that may cause significant performance impact when interacting with the page (on scroll and hovers, but also transitions and animations).

The performance impact is true when you have a few of them (e.g. box shadow, rounded corners and gradients) to fix with CSS3 PIE on the same elements (e.g. menu tabs with hover) at the same time. It's better to use sprites for older browsers and they will be cached too.